# What does "swift spirit-bolsterer from the Traveller’s Repose" mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm reading a short story ["Earth calling Taylor"](http://www.ft.com/intl/cms/s/2/3e898e58-121c-11e0-92d0-00144feabdc0.html#axzz2sSeFbLGo) by David Mitchell right now and I have a problem with understanding this part:

> Problem is, I pre-announced my promotion to the big league on
>   Christmas day and the prospect of their consoling words and unspoken
>   Why-doesn’t-this-surprise-us? is more than I can bear, **even with a
>   swift spirit-bolsterer from the Traveller’s Repose inside me**.

Can you guys help me? What's "spirit-bolster"? What's "Traveller's Repose"? All information I can find about Traveller's Repose on the internet is about [a hotel or something in US](http://www.wvbeard.com/repose.htm) but I think it's not related here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Traveller’s Repose" would be the sort of name one would expect a public house or bar to have. It's a stereotypical sort of name for a pub, describing what a public house was originally intended to provide, and in title-case to make it a name.

It could be he is referring to a particular actual pub, but likely he is using this as an "everyman" of pubs; much as "John Doe" can stand for any person.

A *spirit-bolsterer* in this context is an alcoholic drink taken to steel himself against the prospect he is considering.

*Swift* is often used of such a drink, when taken quickly rather than at a leisurely pace.

So, we could rewrite it with less panache as:

> ... even after a quick drink in the pub to steel myself.

Comment: A belt of whiskey, or a shot of courage, if you will.